# PhpStorm can't detect class type and auto complete

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm

I'm developing a Symfony project and when I use the built-in form to gather the info from the user and make an entity instance out of it, PhpStorm loses track and its autocompleting functionality stops working. It is impossible to cast anything to preferred class in PHP and it works on primitives only I think.

So I tried to check for the instance instead like below:

```
if(form->getData() instanceof MyClass)
    $myInstance = form->getData();
else
    die();

$myInstance->sampleMethod(); // no auto complete!
```

But still, it provides zero help and PhpStorm doesn't know `$myInstance`'s type.

I also tried annotation for where I assign data to the variable but no help here too:

```
/**
* @var MyClass
*/
var $myInstance = form->getData();

$myInstance->sampleMethod(); // no auto complete!
```

Comment: Use correct PHPDoc typehinting for inline variables: `/** @var $myInstance MyClass */`. Or use `instanceof` guard other way around (as the way you use it in your example doesn't help PhpStorm at all): `$myInstance = $form->getData(); if ($myInstance instanceof MyClass) ...`

Comment: Thanks, as I hate to use the PHPDoc middle of a function I prefer to use the second method.